# CloudKeyChainProxy eating CPU

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, icloud, time-machine, keychain

I have the CloudKeyChainProxy process eating my cpu and I can't use keychain any more nor sync with iCloud, I have a backup in time machine, would suggest an action ?

```
EtreCheck version: 2.6.3 (223)
Report generated 11/8/15, 11:33 AM
Runtime 7:00
Download EtreCheck from http://etresoft.com/etrecheck

Click the [Click for support] links for help with non-Apple products.
Click the [Click for details] links for more information about that line.

Hardware Information: (What does this mean?)
MacBook Pro Intel Core i5, Intel Core i7, 13" (Early 2011)
[Click for Technical Specifications]
[Click for User Guide]
MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro8,1
1 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU: 2-core
16 GB RAM Upgradeable
[Click for upgrade instructions]
    BANK 0/DIMM0
        8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
    BANK 1/DIMM0
        8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
Bluetooth: Old - Handoff/Airdrop2 not supported
Wireless:  en1: 802.11 a/b/g/n
Battery: Health = Check Battery - Cycle count = 651 - SN = W012268MAD3LA

Video Information: (What does this mean?)
Intel HD Graphics 3000
    Color LCD 1280 x 800

System Software: (What does this mean?)
OS X El Capitan 10.11 (15A284) - Time since boot: about 2 days

Disk Information: (What does this mean?)
Hitachi HTS545032B9A302 disk0 : (320.07 GB) (Rotational)
    EFI (disk0s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB
    Recovery HD (disk0s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB
    02 (disk1) / : 318.84 GB (169.86 GB free)
        Core Storage: disk0s2 319.21 GB Online

MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898   ()

USB Information: (What does this mean?)
Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver
Apple Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Apple Inc. BRCM2070 Hub
    Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller

Thunderbolt Information: (What does this mean?)
Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Configuration files: (What does this mean?)
/etc/hosts - Count: 1

Gatekeeper: (What does this mean?)
Mac App Store and identified developers

Kernel Extensions: (What does this mean?)
    /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app
[not loaded]    com.parallels.kext.hypervisor (10.1.1 28614 - SDK 10.7)     [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.parallels.kext.netbridge (10.1.1 28614 - SDK 10.7) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.parallels.kext.usbconnect (10.1.1 28614 - SDK 10.7) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.parallels.kext.vnic (10.1.1 28614 - SDK 10.7) [Click for support]

    /Library/Extensions
[loaded]    com.driver.LogJoystick (2.0 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]
[not loaded]    com.logitech.driver.LogiGamingMouseFilter (1 - SDK 10.8) [Click for support]

    /System/Library/Extensions
[loaded]    com.avira.kext.FileAccessControl (1.1.1 - SDK 10.9) [Click for support]

Launch Agents: (What does this mean?)
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.general.agent.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.ipm.ui.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.notifications.agent.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.odscan.default.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.scheduler.agent.plist [Click for support]
[running]    com.avira.antivirus.systray.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.telemetry.agent.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.update.default.plist [Click for support]
[running]    com.avira.helper.avstats.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.realvnc.vncserver.peruser.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.realvnc.vncserver.prelogin.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist [Click for support]

Launch Daemons: (What does this mean?)
[loaded]    com.atlassian.SourceTreePrivilegedHelper2.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.dbcleaner.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.avira.antivirus.ipm.loader.plist [Click for support]
[running]    com.avira.helper.watchdox.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.bombich.ccchelper.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.microsoft.autoupdate.helpertool.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.realvnc.vncserver.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.surteesstudios.Bartender.BartenderInstallHelper.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist [Click for support]

User Launch Agents: (What does this mean?)
[loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist [Click for support]
[loaded]    com.spotify.webhelper.plist [Click for support]

User Login Items: (What does this mean?)
Bartender 2    Application  (/Applications/Bartender 2.app)
smcFanControl    Application  (/Applications/smcFanControl.app)
Dropbox    Application  (/Applications/Dropbox.app)
SpeechSynthesisServer    Application  (/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks /SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesisServer.app)
Logitech Gaming Software    Application Hidden (/Applications/Logitech/Logitech Gaming Software.app)

Other Apps: (What does this mean?)
[running]    com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000002.SourceTree
[running]    com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000003.Slack
[running]    com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000004.Google Chrome
[running]    com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000050.Microsoft Word
[running]    com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000051.Microsoft AU Daemon
[running]    com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x1000006b.EtreCheck
[loaded]    com.batoulapps.GuidanceLauncher
[running]    com.batoulapps.GuidanceMac.53152
[running]    com.eidac.smcFanControl2.69152
[loaded]    com.fiplab.MemoryCleanHelper
[running]    com.fiplab.memoryclean.59232
[loaded]    com.google.Chrome.52512
[running]    com.google.GoogleDrive.170592
[running]    com.microsoft.Powerpoint.61152
[loaded]    com.microsoft.autoupdate.fba.168672
[loaded]    com.simplexsolutionsinc.vpnguardhelperMac
[running]    org.telegram.desktop.72672

Internet Plug-ins: (What does this mean?)
Default Browser: Version: 601 - SDK 10.11
QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
JavaAppletPlugin: Version: Java 8 Update 60 build 27 Check version

User internet Plug-ins: (What does this mean?)
iGetterScriptablePlugin: Version: 2.9.3 [Click for support]

Safari Extensions: (What does this mean?)
Open in Internet Explorer

Audio Plug-ins: (What does this mean?)
BartenderAudioPlugIn: Version: 1.0.0 - SDK 10.10 [Click for support]

3rd Party Preference Panes: (What does this mean?)
Java  [Click for support]
Printopia  [Click for support]

Time Machine: (What does this mean?)
Auto backup: YES
Volumes being backed up:
    02: Disk size: 318.84 GB Disk used: 148.98 GB
Destinations:
    My Passport [Local]
    Total size: 999.83 GB
    Total number of backups: 13
    Oldest backup: 6/11/15, 3:48 AM
    Last backup: 11/3/15, 9:05 PM
    Size of backup disk: Excellent
        Backup size 999.83 GB > (Disk size 318.84 GB X 3)

Top Processes by CPU: (What does this mean?)
    80%    CloudKeychainProxy
     7%    WindowServer
     6%    secd
     4%    syslogd
     2%    SubmitDiagInfo

Top Processes by Memory: (What does this mean?)
2.42 GB    CloudKeychainProxy
2.30 GB    Google Chrome Helper(16)
1.15 GB    kernel_task
590 MB    Slack
426 MB    softwareupdated

Virtual Memory Information: (What does this mean?)
661 MB    Free RAM
15.00 GB    Used RAM (4.16 GB Cached)
33 MB    Swap Used

Diagnostics Information: (What does this mean?)
Nov 8, 2015, 08:07:47 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Microsoft     PowerPoint_2015-11-08-080747_[redacted].hang
Nov 7, 2015, 08:29:37 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Clear_2015-11-07-202937_[redacted].crash
Nov 7, 2015, 04:41:11 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/com.apple.preferences.icloud.remoteservice_201 5-11-07-164111_[redacted].crash
Nov 7, 2015, 01:58:27 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Keychain Access_2015-11-07-135827_[redacted].crash
Nov 7, 2015, 12:08:49 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Clear_2015-11-07-120849_[redacted].crash
Nov 6, 2015, 10:03:54 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/mtmd_2015-11-06-220354_[redacted].cpu_resource. diag [Click for details]
Nov 6, 2015, 07:57:48 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/CloudKeychainProxy_2015-11-06-195748_[redacted] .cpu_resource.diag [Click for details]
Nov 6, 2015, 04:25:04 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SourceKitService_2015-11-06-162504_[redacted]. crash
Nov 6, 2015, 12:02:14 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SourceKitService_2015-11-06-000214_[redacted]. crash
Nov 5, 2015, 10:35:20 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Xcode_2015-11-05-223520_[redacted].crash
Nov 5, 2015, 06:35:11 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/LCore_2015-11-05-183511_[redacted].hang
Nov 5, 2015, 06:31:54 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/com.apple.CommerceKit.TransactionService_2015- 11-05-183154_[redacted].crash
Nov 5, 2015, 06:24:09 PM    Self test - passed
Nov 5, 2015, 06:01:28 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Clear_2015-11-05-180128_[redacted].crash
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as you. I am attempting to get all data off of my Macbook Air, and start from fresh (will report back if this solved issue). This was never an issue with Mavericks or Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan. I had messed about with my KeyChains (probably the likely factor in this issue).

To solve the issue I had to completely wipe my Macbook Air, set up El Capitan and iCloud again.
**Before you attempt to do this, ensure that you have all of your data on backed up to an external drive, not a Time Machine backup.**

As you can see below CloudKeychainProxy is now not hogging CPU cycles, and my battery life has dramatically improved.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: As a side note, I did try my time machine backup from before El Capitan installed but I was still stuck with this issue after upgrading.